# Change town/city text field to Select Option field in checkout form

Tags: php, wordpress, select, woocommerce, checkout

In Woocommerce, I would like to change Town/City text field in a select field option field.

What should i do?

Here is a screenshot:

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need first to change the field **`type`** from **'text'** to **'select'** using the dedicated hook **`woocommerce_default_address_fields`**. Then you have also to change the **`label`** and to and an **`options`** argument where you are going to set your towns in an array of **`key/values`**.

In this array, you will have a line by town separated by a coma.

Here is the code:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_default_address_fields' , 'customize_checkout_city_field' );
function customize_checkout_city_field( $address_fields ) {

    // Set HERE the cities (one line by city)
    $towns_cities_arr = array(
        '0' => __('Select your city', 'my_theme_slug'),
        'paris' => 'Paris',
        'versailles' => 'Versailles',
        'cannes' => 'Cannes',
    );

    // Customizing 'billing_city' field
    $address_fields['city']['type'] = 'select';
    $address_fields['city']['class'] = array('form-row-last', 'my-custom-class'); // your class here
    $address_fields['city']['label'] = __('Town / city', 'my_theme_slug');
    $address_fields['city']['options'] = $towns_cities_arr;


    // Returning Checkout customized fields
    return $address_fields;

}
```

*This code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*

The code is tested and fully functional.

---

**Update:** To add your custom class, replace in **`$address_fields['city']['class']…`** the class **`'my-custom-class'`** by yours.

---

References:

- [Customizing checkout fields using actions and filters - Overriding core fields](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/tutorial-customising-checkout-fields-using-actions-and-filters/#section-2)

Comment: yes and one more thing i want to add class to this field.

Comment: Is it possible to add a search field to the dropdown? I have about 500 towns for users to select from

Answer (score 2):

You can customize the checkout fields by actions and filters.

Please refer the official documentation [here](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/tutorial-customising-checkout-fields-using-actions-and-filters/)

```
    // Add these code in your theme's function.php
add_filter( 'woocommerce_default_address_fields' , 'custom_override_default_address_fields' );

// Our hooked in function - $address_fields is passed via the filter!
function custom_override_default_address_fields( $fields) {

$fields['billing']['your_field']['options'] = array(
  'option_1' => 'Option 1 text',
  'option_2' => 'Option 2 text'
);
     return $fields;
}
```

In case you are looking for a plugin you can use [checkout field editor](https://woocommerce.com/products/woocommerce-checkout-field-editor/) from woocommerce team.